# regression with time series, wanted value is time independent

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series

I hope anyone can help me because i couldnt find any Information on this Topic.

I´m trying to estimate a value (the weight/mass) with machine learning(regression). The data that i have is a time series of physical values of a system, but the value (mass) that im looking for is time independent. It does change sometimes (example: load, fuel, etc.), but im not looking for a forecast. I´d like to estimate this fixed value from my past data. I dont think Dumping the timestamp is a good idea because in a physical context the time derivative of a value ist needed. All ML algorithms i found for time series where about forecasting…

I´d really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction here.

cheers

tim